# Lottery machine probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume we have a lottery machine where you press a button and it returns one of 5 motifs in one of 5 colours. Each of these also has a chance to be gilded.

Assume I have a dataset containing outcomes of this lottery machine. i.e. a list of motifs, their colours and whether or not it is gilded.

How would I go about estimating the probabilities of getting each combination? How would I determine whether gilding probability is independent of motif and/or color?

I'm very familiar with linear normal models, mme models and hypothesis testing in these models but I have no idea how to proceed with a problem like this.

Comment: Make a 3-D contingency table for three categorical variables: 5 levels of motif, 5 levels of color, 2 levels of gilding. So the table has 50 cells altogether. Dividing the count in each cell by the number of outcomes tabled gives the estimated probability for each combination. Standard tests of independence allow testing whether each pair of variables is independent; there is an analogous test for independence of all three.

Comment: @BruceET Can we in any way prove that those estimates are central? What standard indepedence tests are you referring to?

Comment: Google 'chi-squared test of independence'. Not sure what you mean by 'central'.

Comment: @BruceET Oh excuse me, language barrier. I mean unbiased. EDIT: And also, can we say anything about the variance or even distribution of the estimator?

Comment: The observed frequency proportion is an unbiased estimate of the probability because, given the probability,  the expected observed frequency proportion is the probability

Comment: @Henry Right, that makes sense. I'm still sort of confused on how to do a k-way chi-squared independence test.

Comment: Suggest you start testing independence of gilding and motif, and of gilding and color--your stated objectives. For that you need 2-way (marginal) tables, and standard chi-sq test (as described in Wikipedia and many other places.) By then, if you feel a three-way test of indep is necessary, you should be ready for the obvious generalization.